# Is there a man page for `perl` itself?

Tags: perl

I wanted to find out what `perl -T` means.

`man perl` says:

```
PERL(1)                 Perl Programmers Reference Guide          PERL(1)

NAME
  perl - The Perl 5 language interpreter

SYNOPSIS
  perl [ -sTtuUWX ]      [ -hv ] [ -V[:configvar] ]
       [ -cw ] [ -d[t][:debugger] ] [ -D[number/list] ]
       [ -pna ] [ -Fpattern ] [ -l[octal] ] [ -0[octal/hexadecimal] ]
       [ -Idir ] [ -m[-]module ] [ -M[-]'module...' ] [ -f ]  [ -C [number/list] ]  [ -S ]
       [ -x[dir] ]      [ -i[extension] ]
       [ [-e|-E] 'command' ] [ -- ] [ programfile ] [ argument ]...
```

And then explains none of those command line arguments.

Where can I find a manpage/perldoc for those command line arguments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at `perldoc perlrun` ("how to execute the Perl interpreter"):

> `-T`
>
> forces "taint" checks to be turned on so you can test them.
>               Ordinarily these checks are done only when running setuid or
>               setgid.  It's a good idea to turn them on explicitly for programs
>               that run on behalf of someone else whom you might not necessarily
>               trust, such as CGI programs or any internet servers you might
>               write in Perl.  See `perlsec` for details.  For security reasons,
>               this option must be seen by Perl quite early; usually this means
>               it must appear early on the command line or in the `#!` line for
>               systems which support that construct.

Comment: `perldoc` is not installed by default on [Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)).

Comment: @nneonneo thank you. Was having trouble finding the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

From the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches):

> -T
>
> turns on "taint" so you can test them. Ordinarily these checks are done only when running setuid or setgid. It's a good idea to turn them
> on explicitly for programs that run on behalf of someone else whom you
> might not necessarily trust, such as CGI programs or any internet
> servers you might write in Perl. See perlsec for details. For security
> reasons, this option must be seen by Perl quite early; usually this
> means it must appear early on the command line or in the #! line for
> systems which support that construct.